# Load a frozen model into a Tensorflow Estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I am using the new TensorFlow Estimator interface.

I have tested it on the basic MNIST tutorial and the interface seems quite powerful. So I have trained and evaluated a MNIST model.

I have then frozen the model into a single frozen_mnist.pb file.

I was wondering if there is a way to load a frozen model back into a Python Estimator object (e.g. to use it for prediction with the estimator.predict method).

Comment: In TF 1.6, you can use tf.contrib.predictor.from_saved_model("frozen_mnist.pb") ...you can then do inference. But this will not build an Estimator object.